# Why setting level 1 list still affect inner list?

Tags: lists

In the following code, I set level 1 description list

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \begin{document}
        \setlist[description,1]{leftmargin=2.8cm,labelindent=-0.25cm,labelsep*=1cm,style=multiline}
        \begin{description}
            \item[tt] tttt \\
            \item[ttttt] 
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item this separation is too large
                \item this separation is too large
                \item this separation is too large
                \item this separation is too large
            \end{enumerate}  
        \end{description}
    \end{document}
```

It gives

[image]

You can see the separation between label and item is too large for enumerate list. Why? I only set level 1 description list. How to protect inner list from outer list setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent nested lists to overlap, it is necessary that all parameters of the nested list be relative to the `left margin` of the upper level list. You can circumvent this to happen  using the `wide` option of enummitem, and fixing the value of `labelsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\setlist[description,1]{leftmargin=2.8cm,labelindent=-0.25cm,labelsep*=1cm,style=multiline}
\begin{description}
  \item[tt] tttt \\Blah blah blah
  \item[ttttt]
  \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, labelsep =0.5em] %
    \item this separation is too large. this separation is too large. this separation is too large. this separation is too large. this separation is too large. this separation is too large. this separation is too large. this separation is too large.
    \item this separation is too large
    \item this separation is too large
    \item this separation is too large
  \end{enumerate}
\end{description}

\end{document} [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: thank you Bernard. But this is not what i want. i only want to reduce separation in the red circle, while you have also change the indent of whole enumerate list

Comment: I've changed to code . Is it more like you want?

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I want. But I have questions. I think `wide` is already treating the whole enumerate list as a paragraph,  why there should be a `leftmargin=*`?

Comment: Also this problem still remains: "Why only setting level 1 description list affect inner list?"

Comment: @user15964: Unfortunately, I don't have any idea. The internals of description environments remain a mystery to me.